# Response message: Unauthorized in Jmeter

Tags: performance, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter, jmeter-3.2

I'm new to using Jmeter tool.
I have recorded my application using blazemeter (v3.1) and then trying to run that *.jmx* file in Jmeter, however I am running into an authorization issue and the script fails to run.
I have also tried setting my "HTTP Authorization Manager" with username, url, password but it does not help. If anyone can, please guide me on this Issue. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding Authorization header to your HTTP requests?

Answer (score 0):

As per [4 Things You Should Never Do with Your JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/4-things-you-should-never-do-your-jmeter-script) article:

> **Don’t run the script exactly as you recorded it**
>
> After recording your script, there is still some work to do before you run it. It’s necessary to correlate variables, parameterize and add elements, to faithfully simulate users.

There are too many ways of possible authentication implementation in your application, most probably you need to send some dynamic value along with credentials which can be fetched from the previous request.

Record your test scenario 2 times and compare recorded requests. Be careful as differences might be in [response headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) and [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL), not only in response data. It makes sense to add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener directly to [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) - this way you will be able to see what data is captured by JMeter and amend its configuration so simulated request would look exactly like the request from the real browser.